# MATLAB Image Processing - Find Edge and Area of Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

As a preface: this is my first question - I've tried my best to make it as clear as possible, but I apologise if it doesn't meet the required standards.

As part of a summer project, I am taking time-lapse images of an internal melt figure growing inside a crystal of ice. For each of these images I would like to measure the perimeter of, and area enclosed by the figure formed. Linked below is an example of one of my images:

[image]

The method that I'm trying to use is the following:

1. Load image, crop, and convert to grayscale
2. Process to reduce noise
3. Find edge/perimeter
4. Attempt to join edges
5. Fill perimeter with white
6. Measure Area and Perimeter using regionprops

This is the code that I am using:

```
clear; close all;

% load image and convert to grayscale
tyrgb = imread('TyndallTest.jpg');
ty    = rgb2gray(tyrgb);
figure; imshow(ty)

% apply a weiner filter to remove noise.
% N is a measure of the window size for detecting coherent features
N=20;
tywf  = wiener2(ty,[N,N]);
tywf = tywf(N:end-N,N:end-N);

% rescale the image adaptively to enhance contrast without enhancing noise
tywfb = adapthisteq(tywf);

% apply a canny edge detection
tyedb = edge(tywfb,'canny');

%join edges
diskEnt1 = strel('disk',8); % radius of 4
tyjoin1 = imclose(tyedb,diskEnt1);
figure; imshow(tyjoin1)
```

It is at this stage that I am struggling. The edges do not quite join, no matter how much I play around with the morphological structuring element. Perhaps there is a better way to complete the edges? Linked is an example of the figure this code outputs:

[image]

The reason that I am trying to join the edges is so that I can fill the perimeter with white pixels and then use regionprops to output the area. I have tried using the imfill command, but cannot seem to fill the outline as there are a large number of dark regions to be filled within the perimeter.

Is there a better way to get the area of one of these melt figures that is more appropriate in this case?

As background research: I can make this method work for a simple image consisting of a black circle on a white background using the below code. However I don't know how edit it to handle more complex images with edges that are less well defined.

```
clear all
close all
clc

%% Read in RGB image from directory
RGB1 = imread('1.jpg')   ;

%% Convert RPG image to grayscale image
I1 = rgb2gray(RGB1)       ;

%% Transform Image
%CROP
IC1 = imcrop(I1,[74 43 278 285]);

%BINARY IMAGE 
BW1 = im2bw(IC1); %Convert to binary image so the boundary can be traced

%FIND PERIMETER
BWP1 = bwperim(BW1); 
%Traces perimeters of objects & colours them white (1). 
%Sets all other pixels to black (0)
%Doing the same job as an edge detection algorithm?

%FILL PERIMETER WITH WHITE IN ORDER TO MEASURE AREA AND PERIMETER
BWF1 = imfill(BWP1); %This opens  figure and allows you to select the areas to fill with white.

%MEASURE PERIMETER
D1 = regionprops(BWF1, 'area', 'perimeter'); 
%Returns an array containing the properties area and perimeter. 
%D1(1) returns the perimeter of the box and an area value identical to that
%perimeter? The box must be  bounded by a perimeter.
%D1(2) returns the perimeter and area of the section filled in BWF1

%% Display Area and Perimeter data
D1(2)
```

Comment: Upvoted because you've done an excellent job of asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider Active Contours. This will give you a continous boundary of the object rather than patchy edges.

Below are links to

A book:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Active-Contours-Application-Techniques-Statistics/dp/1447115570/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1377248739&sr=8-1-fkmr2&keywords=Active+shape+models+Andrew+Blake%2C+Michael+Isard

A demo:
http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/msn/book/new_demo/Snakes/

and some Matlab code on the File Exchange:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28149-snake-active-contour

and a link to a description on how to implement it: http://www.cb.uu.se/~cris/blog/index.php/archives/217

Using the implementation on the File Exchange, you can get something like this:

```
%% Load the image
% You could use the segmented image obtained previously
% and then apply the snake on that (although I use the original image).
% This will probably make the snake work better and the edges
% in your image is not that well defined.
% Make sure the original and the segmented image 
% have the same size. They don't at the moment
I = imread('33kew0g.jpg');

% Convert the image to double data type
I = im2double(I); 
% Show the image and select some points with the mouse (at least 4)
% figure, imshow(I); [y,x] = getpts; 
% I have pre-selected the coordinates already
x = [  525.8445   473.3837   413.4284   318.9989   212.5783   140.6320    62.6902    32.7125    55.1957    98.6633   164.6141   217.0749   317.5000   428.4172   494.3680   527.3434   561.8177   545.3300];
y = [  435.9251  510.8691  570.8244  561.8311  570.8244  554.3367  476.3949  390.9586  311.5179  190.1085  113.6655   91.1823   98.6767  106.1711  142.1443  218.5872  296.5291      375.9698];

% Make an array with the selected coordinates
P=[x(:) y(:)];
%% Start Snake Process
% You probably have to fiddle with the parameters
% a bit more that I have
Options=struct;
Options.Verbose=true;
Options.Iterations=1000;
Options.Delta = 0.02;
Options.Alpha = 0.5;
Options.Beta = 0.2;
figure(1);
[O,J]=Snake2D(I,P,Options);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have room to improve the effect of edge detection in addition to the morphological transformations, for instance the following resulted in what appeared to me a relatively satisfactory perimeter.

```
tyedb = edge(tywfb,'sobel',0.012);

%join edges

diskEnt1 = strel('disk',7); % radius of 4
tyjoin1 = imclose(tyedb,diskEnt1);
```

In addition I used `bwfill` interactively to fill in most of the interior. It should be possible to fill the interior programatically but I did not pursue this.

```
% interactively fill internal regions

[ny nx] = size(tyjoin1);
figure; imshow(tyjoin1)
tyjoin2=tyjoin1;
titl = sprintf('click on a region to fill\nclick outside window to stop...')
while 1
   pts=ginput(1)
   tyjoin2 = bwfill(tyjoin2,pts(1,1),pts(1,2),8);
   imshow(tyjoin2)
   title(titl)
   if (pts(1,1)<1 | pts(1,1)>nx | pts(1,2)<1 | pts(1,2)>ny), break, end
end
```

This was the result I obtained

[image]

The "fractal" properties of the perimeter may be of importance to you however. Perhaps you want to retain the folds in your shape.

Answer (score 0):

If the end result is an area/diameter estimate, then why not try to find maximal and minimal shapes that fit in the outline and then use the shapes' area to estimate the total area. For instance, compute a minimal circle *around* the edge set then a maximal circle *inside* the edges. Then you could use these to estimate diameter and area of the actual shape.

The advantage is that your bounding shapes can be fit in a way that minimizes error (unbounded edges) while optimizing size either up or down for the inner and outer shape, respectively.

Comment: I hadn't considered that idea - I'll give it a try for an estimate of the area. Unfortunately, I do also need a measurement of the perimeter.

I also wondered if it would be possible to begin with a circle larger than the figure and then shrink it to surround the perimeter . Kind of like a lasso or a shrink-wrap machine. I'm not sure if such an algorithm exists?