# Matlab crop a polygon from an image

Tags: matlab, polygon, crop, bounding-box

I have an image of a product on a solid background that I would like to crop as close as possible to the product.

[image: Original]

I brighten it and find the edges with the following code:

```
limits = stretchlim(original, 0.01);
img1 = imadjust(original, limits, []);

img = rgb2gray(img1);

BW = edge(img,'canny',0.2);

[B,L,N,A] = bwboundaries(BW);
figure; imshow(BW); hold on;
for k=1:length(B),
    if(~sum(A(k,:)))
       boundary = B{k};
     plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'r','LineWidth',2);hold on;
    end
end
```

Which give me the following image:

[image: EdgeDetected]

The following code gives me rectangles on every blob/line detected:

```
blobMeasurements = regionprops(logical(BW), 'BoundingBox');
numberOfBlobs = size(blobMeasurements, 1);

rectCollection = [];
for k = 1 : numberOfBlobs % Loop through all blobs.
rects = blobMeasurements(k).BoundingBox; % Get list ofpixels in current blob.
x1 = rects(1);
y1 = rects(2);
x2 = x1 + rects(3);
y2 = y1 + rects(4);
x = [x1 x2 x2 x1 x1];
y = [y1 y1 y2 y2 y1];
rectCollection(k,:,:,:) = [x1; y1; x2; y2];
end
```

I'm able to then draw a bounding rectangle and crop with all these points collected with the following code:

```
% get min max
xmin=min(rectCollection(:,1))-1;
ymin=min(rectCollection(:,2))-1;
xmax=max(rectCollection(:,3))+1;
ymax=max(rectCollection(:,4))+1;

% define outer rect:
outer_rect=[xmin ymin xmax-xmin ymax-ymin];

crop = imcrop(original,outer_rect);
```

Which gives me the following result:

[image: Result]

My question is how can I get a polygon as close as possible to the product and crop it with the polygon or, alternatively, just crop as close as possible to the product and its cap?

Comment: Is it important that it is a polygon or can it just be a boundary? If it can be a boundary and speed is not a major issue, Active Countours might help. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18399089/2545927

Comment: Active Contours might work but it has to be automatic... Any ideas?

Comment: Apply the code in the link above and see what you get. If it doesn't work, threshold the image and see.

Comment: Still struggling to get a decent method that works consistently

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get a bounding box but a polygon, I think you need to generate a mask - a matrix with the same size of your image, value 1 if the pixel in on your object, 0 if not.

I heard about an algorithm (sorry I can't find the name, I'll edit this post if I find it) which works with a lasso :

- step 0 : your lasso is your bounding box.
- step i : segment the lasso and for each part, you retract it if the color (or any other) gradient in the image is less than a fixed value.
- step n (last) : you cannot retract any part of the lasso, it is finished. Inside your lasso : your object. Outside : the background.

As I remember there is a lot of work with this method : the definition of the lasso, the retractation step, the solidity of your lasso (to avoid too much deformation of the lasso).

Beside the lasso method you can search about the [watershed transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_%28image_processing%29), it can also work with your problem.

Finally, if you generate the pictures, take shots with a plained background (green, pink, blue, etc) and use a simple [chromakey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key).

Answer (score 0):

Using active contours also looks like a good approach but getting a nice mask is troublesome.

```
original = imread('1.jpg');
level = graythresh(original);
img = rgb2gray(original);
mask = im2bw(img,level+0.1);

mask = imfill(~mask,'holes');

bw = activecontour(img,mask);

rows = numel(original(:,1,1));
columns = numel(original(1,:,1));

for i = 1:rows
    for j = 1:columns
        if (  bw(i,j,1) == 0 )
            original(i,j,:) = 255;
         end
    end
end

imshow(original);
```