# Detect Main Object in Image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy, computer-vision

I have images that will look like the one below. My first idea is to use flood-fill starting from the corners of the image, to make a mask that I can then extract the shoe later. Is there a better way with Opencv or a different Python library?

[image]

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? Can't you use Python Image Library (PIL) to detect all white pixels? Maybe you also want to look into Canny Edge Detection (http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html)?

Comment: I don't want edges, I want a mask with which I can extract all the pixels of the shoe. Also, I will not know whether the background will always be white

Comment: Okay, that's clear. Unfortunately I cannot help you further either. :-(

Comment: No worries! hopefully someone will have had this problem before

Comment: Active contours might be what you are looking for (although they are slow). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18399089/2545927) for an idea of what to do. It's for Matlab though but I'm sure you can find something similar for Python/OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

There was a post on Lyst about exactly that problem. And by exactly I mean segmenting shoes. Here's the [link](http://developers.lyst.com/data/images/2014/02/13/background-removal/)

Basically, the steps they used were :

1. Inverting the colors
2. Applying Sobel filter
3. Applying gaussian blur
4. Thresholding
5. Flood fill

The example is complete with python code snippet at the end.

In your case, if you always have white background, you could probably just use thresholding.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am remove pixel with color value,
you can modify it.

```
from PIL import Image
#here i am using 1.jpg to 40.jpg images
#code will remove all pixel which is graterthan (245,245,245)
for i in range(1,41):
    i = str(i)
    img = Image.open(i+'.jpg') #open image
    img = img.convert("RGBA")
    datas = img.getdata()
    newData = []
    for item in datas:
        if item[0] >= 245 and item[1] >= 245 and item[2] >= 245:    #check pixel color
            newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))                   
        else:
            newData.append(item)
    i = int(i)
    print i 
    img.putdata(newData)
    i = str(i)
    #img = img.convert("LA") convert image in Grayscale
    img.save(i+'.png', "PNG") #save as png file
```