# Extract co-ordinates from detected contour

Tags: matlab, image-processing, contour, grayscale, feature-extraction

I want to detect the contour of a ring/disc which may be rotated in 3D. I used [Detect circles with various radii in grayscale image via Hough Transform](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9168-detect-circles-with-various-radii-in-grayscale-image-via-hough-transform) by Tao Peng. The results were very close to my requirement. Except for two points:

1. Using Tao Peng's code I could get a neat blue line indicating the detected contour. I want to access these co-ordinates (sub-pixels) for further processing. I could not figure out where these co-ordinates of detected contour are stored. If you have any idea, please let me know.
2. Is there any such code to detect ellipse and not only circles? This is because a ring when rotated in 3D wouldn't necessarily be a circle (in which case Tao Peng's code fails. But this is the best I have come across till date. I do not want to binarize my image, as I'll be losing out on a lot of information). Do let me know if there's anything.

Apart from this code, if there's any other one which does a similar job (even if it is like Tao Peng's code, for circles, plus gives me the co-ordinate values), please tell me.

I would prefer MATLAB, but C would also do.

This is an example image who's contour I want to detect, with high accuracy. (The outline of silver disc)

[image]

Regards.

Edit:

Here is an example of my output using Tao Peng's code.

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at Active Contours although they are quite slow. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18399089/2545927). The link to the demo will show you what it can do.

Comment: I do not have Control System Toolbox and System Identification Toolbox, which it says is required to use the command 'interp'.  Also, the processing speed I intend to obtain will not support the fact that I have to click on every image using this code.

Comment: Well, that implementation of Active Contours requires Image Processing Toolbox. You don't have to click if you don't want to. You can specify a rectangle programmatically. Have a look at the example. However, Active Contours are slow in general.

Comment: I have Image Processing Toolbox and Computer Vision System Toolbox. This is the error I am getting:

To use 'interp', you might need:
  interp - Control System Toolbox
  interp - Signal Processing Toolbox
  interp - System Identification Toolbox

Error in InterpolateContourPoints2D (line 32)
O(:,1)=interp([P(end-3:end,1);P(:,1);P(:,1);P(1:4,1)],10);

Error in Snake2D (line 127)
P=InterpolateContourPoints2D(P,Options.nPoints);

Comment: It says you **might** need it. It worked for me and I don't have Control or Systems identification toolbox. It was just a suggestion that may help you to solve your problem. You don't have to use it.

Comment: I am able to run the example in Snake3D.m, but it does not do what I intend to do. None of the examples in Snake2D.m work (  That's when I get the error mentioned above, therefore not able to proceed with the line "O,J]=Snake2D(I,P,Options);"   ) Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is there anything else you require to know to help me out?